# Can Mono for Android be used with Visual Web Developer Express?

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, visual-web-developer-2010

I downloaded Mono for Android and was following the tutorial on installation. I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express I got up to [this part](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Installation_for_Windows#Configuring_Visual_Studio), where you configure the VS settings, but I don't see "Mono for Android" in the options of VWD.

Is Visual Web Developer supported? Can I used Mono with it?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the express editions of Visual Studio 2010 do not support plugins, which is required by Mono for Android, so it is not supported. You can, however, use MonoDevelop on Windows which has full Mono for Android support. MonoDevelop is free and open source, and is installed automatically as part of Mono for Android's installer.